# in docker bash how to change the installation location for the pip install?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, pip, mount

I try to install the pip files on docker bash
first of all I started the docker image with

```
sudo nvidia-docker run --rm -it --ipc=host -v /home/ubuntu/:/home/ubuntu/ -v /home/ubuntu/:/home/ubuntu/ king/pytorch:latest /bin/bas
```

then I try to install the pip libraries
the location of the libraries is in

```
/opt/conda/
```

but it said the disk is full so no more installation is available.
in this case how should I move the install location ?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          48G   42G  3.2G  93% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs            89G     0   89G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdb       2.0T  848G  1.2T  43% /home/ubuntu
/dev/xvda1       48G   42G  3.2G  93% /etc/hosts
```

file system is looks like this and the I guess /opt is in / location

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the Docker image installation folder.
Have a look into the steps here : https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169